# Tableau Extract like functionality with Presto

Tags: postgresql, tableau-api, reporting, presto, in-memory

I was designing a custom reporting tool( not for data warehousing)  with normal analytical dashboard in my mind.
As of now I am planning to use PostgreSQL as my reporting database since I have all the basic analytical functions available there.But when it comes to do some on the fly lookup on raw data the response time is too bad.For each user action one query is running on postgresDB is not so efficient.

In-memory approach like Tableau extracts is a perfect fit for these kind of use case.Is it possible for me to achieve something similar using Presto in between Postgres and reporting layer, so that Presto will run queries on top of raw data and yield faster result?

Suppose I am talking about a table 'order' and searching for some specific item category and again filtering on sub category and so on,whether presto will submit each queries to Postgres for each user action or it will intelligently filter out data which is already present in the presto layer?

If Presto is not the right solution for this ,is there any DB/engines present to solve these kind of in-memory dynamic reporting similar to tableau extracts?

Answer (score 0):

Presto won't yield much value when deployed on top of single RDBMS instance (here: PostgreSQL). Presto would still need to fetch data from the underlying database and will be constrained by your PostgreSQL's efficiency.

However, with Presto you can use additional data stores -- e.g. you can experiment with [Presto's builtin memory connector](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/memory.html) or use some NoSQL database for fast access to individual records.

Also, you should consider if modeling your data differently could bring some improvement. Perhaps you could use some Cube / Data Mart (e.g. [Druid](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/pull/532)) solution for faster access to aggregated results. If you use Presto as a data virtualization layer, you retain freedom to change underlying technologies without changing your custom reporting tool at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.I just had a quick read about Presto Memory connector.Is that production ready implementation or still in Beta stage.

Comment: @AnoopR it's works, but it has limitations. Use judiciously, i.e. it may or may not fit in your setup.

Comment: True need to heavily test whether this will fit the bill or complicate things.If data is not that big say <20GB we can even leverage in-memory SQL-lite option also (Never tried just read about that) Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Presto has [Postrgres support](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/connector/postgresql.html) but if you need Tableau-like functionality just use Tableau?

Alternatively, you could look to tune your indexes and other Postgres parameters to get better performance from that database natively.

Comment: We don't need complete Tableau's functionality .We are interested in extract (in-memory) functionality in Tableau